# Configure VS Code to use .jar files when doing live syntax checking

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

How do I configure VS Code to use the .jar files in my lib directory when doing live syntax checking? I can compile and run my code without any problems using the "Debug" menu in VS Code; but the editor is marking every reference to JUnit classes/methods as a syntax error.

I have a very simple standalone Java "project": One source file, one JUnit source file, and a lib directory containing the JUnit and Hamcrest .jar files.  As suggested by this document: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project, simply placing the .jar files in a lib directory should be sufficient. It is when it comes to compiling and running the code; but, my editor is full of red squiggly lines.

---

Update:  I tried refreshing the workspace cache, and now it won't even compile and run.  Am I misunderstanding the directions; or, so I have a setting messed up somewhere?

Comment: Try to add the jar path to the `.classpath` file,you could refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_adding-external-jar

Comment: There is no `.classpath` file.

Comment: If you follow the https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project link to create a project,you should have the `.classpath` file,or you could try to create a new project